# marque alignment not proper in html

Tags: html, css

I want the marque to be in the premises of the green board in the image. But the marque is not aligned. Please tell me how to do.
Here is the following code . 
The text is going above the green board.. How to correct that?

```css
#test {
    background: url("http://s14.postimg.org/z0bjc6vht/boarlad_1.png") no-repeat top left;
    height: 540px; /*image height*/
    width: 960px; /*image width*/
    position; relative;
    color: white;
}
.box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 200px;   
    width: 530px;
    height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Presentation 1</h2>
<a href="index.html"><h3>Back to Main Page</h3></a>
<div id="test">
    <div class="box">
        <marquee style ="top:100px;"scrollamount="2" direction="up"  scrolldelay="1" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()" width="100%"/>
        <font color="white"><strong> There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text!
        </strong></font></marquee>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you can do something like this :

example: http://jsfiddle.net/gf2eoenc/

First of all we get rid of the inline style from marquee, then we wrap it with container div (`<div id="marquee-container">`).

Also we set `overflow: hidden;` on div with `class: box;` that means that all content will be nested inside this div and won't get outside its containing block (div with class box in our example).

Next what we should do is to "play" with width/height/top properties of the div with class box to adjust it as we want.

You set it's properties as px (pixels) i recommend you to use percentage / em instead .

HTML:

```
<h2>Presentation 1</h2>
<a href="index.html"><h3>Back to Main Page</h3></a>
<div id="test">
<div class="box">
    <div id="marquee-container">
    <marquee  scrollamount="2" direction="up"  scrolldelay="1" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()" />
    <font color="white"><strong> There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text! There will be text!
    </strong></font></marquee>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
background: url("http://s14.postimg.org/z0bjc6vht/boarlad_1.png") no-repeat top left;
height: 540px; /*image height*/
width: 960px; /*image width*/
position; relative;
color: white;
}
.box {
position: absolute;
left: 300px;
top: 141px;   
width: 550px;
height: 330px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.box #marquee-container {
 width: 500px;
height: 280px;
}
```

HTH.